# PHP error when input contains "/"

Tags: php, preg-match

When the input string contains a "/" symbol, I'm getting a PHP error:

Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier

How can I resolve it?

```
$token = '/<'.$tag.'[^>]*>(.*\b'.$keyword.'\b.*)<\/'.$tag.'>/siU';
if(preg_match($token, &$content, $matches))
{
    $match = 1;
}
return $match;
```

Comment: did u try to replace it with "\/" ?

Comment: No, I might try that though. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to escape tag and keyword, like this:

```
$token = '/<' . preg_quote($tag, '/') . '[^>]*>(.*\b' . preg_quote($keyword, '/')
         . '\b.*)<\/' . preg_quote($tag, '/') . '>/siU';
```

Answer (score 2):

[preg_quote](http://php.net/preg_quote) function should help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

You use input in regexp pattern - you should escape all special sequences. Try `addcslashes` function

Comment: `php > echo addslashes('.*');` returns `.*`, so this is not the best idea :)